# Post name permalinks File not found -- Mac High Sierra

Tags: permalinks, mac

I have read the instructions on the Wordpress site, and have read some lengthy posts here but nothing specific to this environment
Environment:

- Mac OS X High Sierra
- PHP v 7.1.33
- Apache v 2.4.33
- Wordpress v 5.4.1

1) Uncommented `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` in `httpd.conf`

2) Created a new `.htaccess` in my wordpress root directory (permissions 666):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between BEGIN WordPress and END WordPress are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

3) Changed httpd.conf

```
<Directory />

AllowOverride All

Require all Granted

</Directory>
```

I have restarted the apache. Shut down and restarted the Mac.
Still get a 404 when I set permalinks to Post name.

What am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

I think the .htaccess file looks okay. The problem might be flush rewrite rule.

If you go to the backend: Settings >> Permalink page. Just open the page. No need to do any changes.

And then check, It should resolve the problem.

Thank You

Comment: Not sure what you are suggesting exactly. I can toggle back and forth between "Plain" and "Post name" with "Save Changes" in between. If I leave it on Plain, I get working plain links. If I set it to Post name, I get File not found.